# sitecore workbox does not prompt for comment when approving multiple items

Tags: sitecore

I have a sitecore workflow. When I approve an item with the Approve button right next to the item it asks for comment. When I approve multiple items using the Approve (selected) or Approve (all) buttons it does not ask for comment. Why is that? Can I make it ask for comment and associate that comment with all the items that being approved? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to enable comments for `Selected` or `All` items you need to:

1. Copy `Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Workbox\Workbox.xml` to `Website\sitecore\shell\Override\` directory and change `<CodeBeside Type="..." />` to `<CodeBeside Type="My.Assembly.Namespace.WorkboxForm,My.Assembly" />` where `My.Assembly` and `My.Assembly.Namespace` matches your project.
2. Create your own class `WorkboxForm` that will override Sitecore `WorkboxForm` and match `Type` from point **1.** and use the edited code of `WorkBox` form:

```cs
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Exceptions;
using Sitecore.Globalization;
using Sitecore.Resources;
using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.CommandBuilders;
using Sitecore.Text;
using Sitecore.Web;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls;
using Sitecore.Workflows;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;

namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
    public class WorkboxForm : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm
    {
        private NameValueCollection stateNames;

        public void CommentMultiple(ClientPipelineArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            if (!args.IsPostBack)
            {
                Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Input("Enter a comment:", string.Empty);
                args.WaitForPostBack();
            }
            else if (args.Result.Length > 2000)
            {
                Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.ShowError(new Exception(string.Format("The comment is too long.\n\nYou have entered {0} characters.\nA comment cannot contain more than 2000 characters.", args.Result.Length)));
                Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Input("Enter a comment:", string.Empty);
                args.WaitForPostBack();
            }
            else
            {
                if (args.Result == null || args.Result == "null" || args.Result == "undefined")
                    return;

                IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Context.ContentDatabase.WorkflowProvider;
                if (workflowProvider == null)
                    return;
                IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["workflowid"] as string);
                if (workflow == null)
                    return;

                string stateId = (string)Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["ws"];
                string command = (string)Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["command"];

                string[] itemRefs = ((string)Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["ids"] ?? string.Empty).Split(new[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                bool flag = false;

                int num = 0;

                foreach (string itemRef in itemRefs)
                {
                    string[] strArray = itemRef.Split(new[] { ',' });
                    Item items = Context.ContentDatabase.Items[strArray[0], Language.Parse(strArray[1]), Sitecore.Data.Version.Parse(strArray[2])];
                    if (items != null)
                    {
                        WorkflowState state = workflow.GetState(items);
                        if (state.StateID == stateId)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                workflow.Execute(command, items, args.Result, true, new object[0]);
                            }
                            catch (WorkflowStateMissingException)
                            {
                                flag = true;
                            }
                            ++num;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (flag)
                    SheerResponse.Alert("One or more items could not be processed because their workflow state does not specify the next step.", new string[0]);

                if (num == 0)
                {
                    Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("There are no selected items.");
                }
                else
                {
                    UrlString urlString = new UrlString(WebUtil.GetRawUrl());
                    urlString["reload"] = "1";
                    Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.SetLocation(urlString.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        public override void HandleMessage(Message message)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(message, "message");
            switch (message.Name)
            {
                case "workflow:sendselectednew":
                    SendSelectedNew(message);
                    return;
                case "workflow:sendallnew":
                    SendAllNew(message);
                    return;
            }
            base.HandleMessage(message);
        }

        protected override void DisplayState(IWorkflow workflow, WorkflowState state, DataUri[] items, System.Web.UI.Control control, int offset, int pageSize)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(workflow, "workflow");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(state, "state");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(items, "items");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(control, "control");
            if (items.Length <= 0)
                return;
            int num = offset + pageSize;
            if (num > items.Length)
                num = items.Length;
            for (int index = offset; index < num; ++index)
            {
                Item obj = Context.ContentDatabase.Items[items[index]];
                if (obj != null)
                    CreateItem(workflow, obj, control);
            }
            Border border1 = new Border();
            border1.Background = "#e9e9e9";
            Border border2 = border1;
            control.Controls.Add(border2);
            border2.Margin = "0px 4px 0px 16px";
            border2.Padding = "2px 8px 2px 8px";
            border2.Border = "1px solid #999999";
            foreach (WorkflowCommand workflowCommand in WorkflowFilterer.FilterVisibleCommands(workflow.GetCommands(state.StateID)))
            {
                XmlControl xmlControl1 = (XmlControl) Resource.GetWebControl("WorkboxCommand");
                Assert.IsNotNull(xmlControl1, "workboxCommand is null");
                xmlControl1["Header"] = (workflowCommand.DisplayName + " " + Translate.Text("(selected)"));
                xmlControl1["Icon"] = workflowCommand.Icon;
                xmlControl1["Command"] = ("workflow:sendselectednew(command=" + workflowCommand.CommandID + ",ws=" + state.StateID + ",wf=" + workflow.WorkflowID + ")");
                border2.Controls.Add(xmlControl1);
                XmlControl xmlControl2 = (XmlControl) Resource.GetWebControl("WorkboxCommand");
                Assert.IsNotNull(xmlControl2, "workboxCommand is null");
                xmlControl2["Header"] = (workflowCommand.DisplayName + " " + Translate.Text("(all)"));
                xmlControl2["Icon"] = workflowCommand.Icon;
                xmlControl2["Command"] = ("workflow:sendallnew(command=" + workflowCommand.CommandID + ",ws=" + state.StateID + ",wf=" + workflow.WorkflowID + ")");
                border2.Controls.Add(xmlControl2);
            }
        }

        private static void CreateCommand(IWorkflow workflow, WorkflowCommand command, Item item, XmlControl workboxItem)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(workflow, "workflow");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(command, "command");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(workboxItem, "workboxItem");
            XmlControl xmlControl = (XmlControl) Resource.GetWebControl("WorkboxCommand");
            Assert.IsNotNull(xmlControl, "workboxCommand is null");
            xmlControl["Header"] = command.DisplayName;
            xmlControl["Icon"] = command.Icon;
            CommandBuilder commandBuilder = new CommandBuilder("workflow:send");
            commandBuilder.Add("id", item.ID.ToString());
            commandBuilder.Add("la", item.Language.Name);
            commandBuilder.Add("vs", item.Version.ToString());
            commandBuilder.Add("command", command.CommandID);
            commandBuilder.Add("wf", workflow.WorkflowID);
            commandBuilder.Add("ui", command.HasUI);
            commandBuilder.Add("suppresscomment", command.SuppressComment);
            xmlControl["Command"] = commandBuilder.ToString();
            workboxItem.AddControl(xmlControl);
        }

        private void CreateItem(IWorkflow workflow, Item item, System.Web.UI.Control control)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(workflow, "workflow");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(control, "control");
            XmlControl workboxItem = (XmlControl) Resource.GetWebControl("WorkboxItem");
            Assert.IsNotNull(workboxItem, "workboxItem is null");
            control.Controls.Add(workboxItem);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(" - (");
            Language language = item.Language;
            stringBuilder.Append(language.CultureInfo.DisplayName);
            stringBuilder.Append(", ");
            stringBuilder.Append(Translate.Text("version"));
            stringBuilder.Append(' ');
            stringBuilder.Append(item.Version);
            stringBuilder.Append(")");
            Assert.IsNotNull(workboxItem, "workboxItem");
            workboxItem["Header"] = item.DisplayName;
            workboxItem["Details"] = (stringBuilder).ToString();
            workboxItem["Icon"] = item.Appearance.Icon;
            workboxItem["ShortDescription"] = item.Help.ToolTip;
            workboxItem["History"] = GetHistory(workflow, item);
            workboxItem["HistoryMoreID"] = Control.GetUniqueID("ctl");
            workboxItem["HistoryClick"] = ("workflow:showhistory(id=" + item.ID + ",la=" + item.Language.Name + ",vs=" + item.Version + ",wf=" + workflow.WorkflowID + ")");
            workboxItem["PreviewClick"] = ("Preview(\"" + item.ID + "\", \"" + item.Language + "\", \"" + item.Version + "\")");
            workboxItem["Click"] = ("Open(\"" + item.ID + "\", \"" + item.Language + "\", \"" + item.Version + "\")");
            workboxItem["DiffClick"] = ("Diff(\"" + item.ID + "\", \"" + item.Language + "\", \"" + item.Version + "\")");
            workboxItem["Display"] = "none";
            string uniqueId = Control.GetUniqueID(string.Empty);
            workboxItem["CheckID"] = ("check_" + uniqueId);
            workboxItem["HiddenID"] = ("hidden_" + uniqueId);
            workboxItem["CheckValue"] = (item.ID + "," + item.Language + "," + item.Version);
            foreach (WorkflowCommand command in WorkflowFilterer.FilterVisibleCommands(workflow.GetCommands(item)))
                CreateCommand(workflow, command, item, workboxItem);
        }

        private string GetHistory(IWorkflow workflow, Item item)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(workflow, "workflow");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
            WorkflowEvent[] history = workflow.GetHistory(item);
            string str;
            if (history.Length > 0)
            {
                WorkflowEvent workflowEvent = history[history.Length - 1];
                string text = workflowEvent.User;
                string name = Context.Domain.Name;
                if (text.StartsWith(name + "\\", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    text = StringUtil.Mid(text, name.Length + 1);
                str = string.Format(Translate.Text("{0} changed from <b>{1}</b> to <b>{2}</b> on {3}."),
                                    StringUtil.GetString(new[]
                                        {
                                            text,
                                            Translate.Text("Unknown")
                                        }), GetStateName(workflow, workflowEvent.OldState),
                                    GetStateName(workflow, workflowEvent.NewState),
                                    DateUtil.FormatDateTime(workflowEvent.Date, "D", Context.User.Profile.Culture));
            }
            else
                str = Translate.Text("No changes have been made.");
            return str;
        }

        private static DataUri[] GetItems(WorkflowState state, IWorkflow workflow)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(state, "state");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(workflow, "workflow");
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
            DataUri[] items = workflow.GetItems(state.StateID);
            if (items != null)
            {
                foreach (DataUri index in items)
                {
                    Item obj = Context.ContentDatabase.Items[index];
                    if (obj != null && obj.Access.CanRead() && (obj.Access.CanReadLanguage() && obj.Access.CanWriteLanguage()) && (Context.IsAdministrator || obj.Locking.CanLock() || obj.Locking.HasLock()))
                        arrayList.Add(index);
                }
            }
            return arrayList.ToArray(typeof(DataUri)) as DataUri[];
        }

        private string GetStateName(IWorkflow workflow, string stateID)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(workflow, "workflow");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(stateID, "stateID");
            if (stateNames == null)
            {
                stateNames = new NameValueCollection();
                foreach (WorkflowState workflowState in workflow.GetStates())
                    stateNames.Add(workflowState.StateID, workflowState.DisplayName);
            }
            return StringUtil.GetString(new[] {stateNames[stateID], "?"});
        }

        private void SendAll(Message message)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(message, "message");
            IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Context.ContentDatabase.WorkflowProvider;
            if (workflowProvider == null)
                return;
            string workflowID = message["wf"];
            string stateID = message["ws"];
            IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(workflowID);
            if (workflow == null)
                return;
            WorkflowState state = workflow.GetState(stateID);
            DataUri[] items = GetItems(state, workflow);
            Assert.IsNotNull(items, "uris is null");
            string comments = state != null ? state.DisplayName : string.Empty;
            bool flag = false;
            foreach (DataUri index in items)
            {
                Item obj = Context.ContentDatabase.Items[index];
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        workflow.Execute(message["command"], obj, comments, true, new object[0]);
                    }
                    catch (WorkflowStateMissingException)
                    {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag)
                SheerResponse.Alert("One or more items could not be processed because their workflow state does not specify the next step.", new string[0]);
            UrlString urlString = new UrlString(WebUtil.GetRawUrl());
            urlString["reload"] = "1";
            Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.SetLocation(urlString.ToString());
        }

        private void SendAllNew(Message message)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(message, "message");
            IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Context.ContentDatabase.WorkflowProvider;
            if (workflowProvider == null)
                return;
            string workflowID = message["wf"];
            string stateID = message["ws"];
            IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(workflowID);
            if (workflow == null)
                return;

            if (message["ui"] != "1")
            {
                if (message["suppresscomment"] != "1")
                {
                    string ids = String.Empty;

                    WorkflowState state = workflow.GetState(stateID);
                    DataUri[] items = GetItems(state, workflow);

                    foreach (DataUri dataUri in items)
                    {
                        ids += dataUri.ItemID + "," + dataUri.Language + "," + dataUri.Version.Number + "," + "::";
                    }

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
                    {
                        Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("There are no selected items.");
                        return;
                    }

                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["ids"] = ids;
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["language"] = message["la"];
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["version"] = message["vs"];
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["command"] = message["command"];
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["ws"] = message["ws"];
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["workflowid"] = workflowID;
                    Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "CommentMultiple");
                    return;
                }
            }

            // no comment - use the old SendAll
            SendAll(message);
        }

        private void SendSelectedNew(Message message)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(message, "message");
            IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Context.ContentDatabase.WorkflowProvider;
            if (workflowProvider == null)
                return;
            string workflowID = message["wf"];

            IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(workflowID);
            if (workflow == null)
                return;

            if (message["ui"] != "1")
            {
                if (message["suppresscomment"] != "1")
                {
                    string ids = String.Empty;
                    foreach (string str2 in Context.ClientPage.ClientRequest.Form.Keys)
                    {
                        if (str2 != null && str2.StartsWith("check_", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                        {
                            ids += Context.ClientPage.ClientRequest.Form["hidden_" + str2.Substring(6)] + "::";
                        }
                    }

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
                    {
                        Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("There are no selected items.");
                        return;
                    }

                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["ids"] = ids;
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["language"] = message["la"];
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["version"] = message["vs"];
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["command"] = message["command"];
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["ws"] = message["ws"];
                    Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["workflowid"] = workflowID;
                    Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "CommentMultiple");
                    return;
                }
            }

            // no comment - use the old SendSelected
            SendSelected(message);
        }

        private void SendSelected(Message message, string comment = null)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(message, "message");
            IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Context.ContentDatabase.WorkflowProvider;
            if (workflowProvider == null)
                return;
            string workflowID = message["wf"];
            string str1 = message["ws"];
            IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(workflowID);
            if (workflow == null)
                return;
            int num = 0;
            bool flag = false;
            foreach (string str2 in Context.ClientPage.ClientRequest.Form.Keys)
            {
                if (str2 != null && str2.StartsWith("check_", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    string[] strArray = Context.ClientPage.ClientRequest.Form["hidden_" + str2.Substring(6)].Split(new [] { ',' });
                    Item obj = Context.ContentDatabase.Items[strArray[0], Language.Parse(strArray[1]), Sitecore.Data.Version.Parse(strArray[2])];
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        WorkflowState state = workflow.GetState(obj);
                        if (state.StateID == str1)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                workflow.Execute(message["command"], obj, comment ?? state.DisplayName, true, new object[0]);
                            }
                            catch (WorkflowStateMissingException)
                            {
                                flag = true;
                            }
                            ++num;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag)
                SheerResponse.Alert("One or more items could not be processed because their workflow state does not specify the next step.", new string[0]);
            if (num == 0)
            {
                Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("There are no selected items.");
            }
            else
            {
                UrlString urlString = new UrlString(WebUtil.GetRawUrl());
                urlString["reload"] = "1";
                Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.SetLocation(urlString.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```